# Historical example of research papers being misinterpreted due to poor wording and creating controversy?

Tags: mathematics, physics, social-context, language

Is there any example of major controversy in the scientific community caused due to poor wording and/or misinterpretation of words?

Comment: I recall that a famous scientific paper published by a group of scientist describing the complex structures and movements of our hand. However, at one instant the authors alleged that the hand was an art of god (not sure if this was the actual statement) and it caused a major controversy but it turned out to be a poor translated statement which was intended to be the word "nature" instead of "god"

Comment: [Did the Nobel committee get the physics wrong? Science 2016](https://www.science.org/content/article/did-nobel-committee-get-physics-wrong)

Comment: [Fermi's paper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi's_interaction) on beta decay was rejected by *Nature* in what the journal later described as one of its greatest editorial blunders of all-time.  In mathematics, Galois' papers were famously indecipherable and rejected by Cauchy and others at the Academy.

Comment: Do  controversies coming  for badly summarized scientific papers in the news count?

Comment: The infamous rejection by Nature was not due to linguistic issues and was actually due to the fact that the paper was deemed to be ''excessively theoretical'' and ''divorced from reality''.  This was indeed perhaps the biggest editorial blunder of all time.

Comment: @NWR: I believe the culprit is Poisson who couldn't understand Galois' work and put it for years in a drawer. Cauchy rejected Galois because of their strong political enmity.

Comment: What about the intersection between the scientific community and the non-scientific one? The phrase "scientific theory" has to be right up there in terms of "poorly worded, causing controversy".

Answer (score 33):

[Giovanni Schiaparelli](http://scihi.org/giovanni-schiaparelli-martian-canals/) ...
He wrote in 1877 about his telescopic observations of Mars.  He described some features using the Italian word *canali*.  English translation would be *channels*.  But the term was mistranslated as English *canals*, which was taken to mean they were artificial constructions.  This led to much controversy about whether Mars was inhabited!

Comment: Many  other astronomers saw lines on the surface of Mars, and some described them as canals.  Percival Lowell wrote whole  books about the lines he saw and his interpretation of them as artifical irrigation canals made by the Martians.  That was based more on his observations and interpretatins of them than on the word used to translate Sciaparelli.

Comment: @M.A.Golding Lowell only got involved in 1890s. The public frenzy started in the early 1880s, and the translation of *canali* as canals at a time when Suez was recently completed and Panama was under construction definitely had something to do with it. This is documented e.g. by Slugg's 1882 letter to Manchester Guardian. No astronomers described the "lines" as canals before English and French "creative" translations spread, and several suggested that Schiaparelli depicted boundaries of color shades as lines, see e.g. [Sheehan](http://legacy.adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1997JBAA..107...11S).

Comment: "*Clearly he had channels rather
than canals in mind (with its connotation of artificial
construction). Indeed, in his 1878 Memoir, in which he
discusses the observations in detail, he tends to use the terms canale and fiume (or river) rather indiscriminately, and all
of his canali are given the names of rivers. But of course it was as canals that the term was translated...*" Btw, Schiaparelli was color blind, which explains why he saw color shades differently.

Comment: Well,  a  "canal"  is merely a man-made "channel," so there's that!

Answer (score 8):

*Airborne Contagion and Air Hygiene* by [William Firth Wells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_F._Wells) was one of the earliest works on disease transmission through air. There was research in there showing that droplets *in general* will tend to stay airborne the longest if they are around 100 microns in size. There was also a specific study included which showed that tuberculosis *in particular* is infectious if the droplets are under 5 microns (note that tuberculosis specifically needs to reach a deep section of the lungs in order to infect someone--deeper than other diseases). But apparently people skimmed over the 100 microns part and fixated on the 5 microns part. Fast forward to 2020 and now we have an [article](https://www.wired.com/story/the-teeny-tiny-scientific-screwup-that-helped-covid-kill/) explaining how this misunderstanding lead to COVID guidance such as "3-6 feet apart". (Further reading: [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wells_curve).)

> What must have happened, she thought, was that after Wells died, scientists inside the CDC conflated his observations. They plucked the size of the particle that transmits tuberculosis out of context, making 5 microns stand in for a general definition of airborne spread.

Answer (score 2):

[Paxos Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paxos_(computer_science)) by [Leslie Lamport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leslie_Lamport) comes to my mind.

> I submitted the paper to TOCS in 1990.  All three referees said that
> the paper was mildly interesting, though not very important, but that
> all the Paxos stuff had to be removed.  I was quite annoyed at how
> humorless everyone working in the field seemed to be, so I did nothing
> with the paper.

See paper [123] from [his webpage](http://lamport.azurewebsites.net/pubs/pubs.html#lamport-paxos).

Comment: Welcome to HSMSE. What you wrote does not suggest any type of controversy or of poor wording.

Comment: But it does suggest that Lamport’s words were being misinterpreted.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist  It only suggests that "We  TOCS referees have no sense of humor of which we are aware"  :-)   (with apologies to MIB)

Comment: Not really? it seems to suggest everyone working in the field was humourless

Comment: @user253751 - that was then, now we know some have a sense of humor and that all the humourless types gravitate to SE where they populate plenty of the stacks here, especially scifi.

Comment: It is very difficult to see the controversy you mention. After reading the [123] section you cite, it is still not clear what Paxos means, why the referees wanted the Paxos stuff to be removed. Not being native speaker, am I missing some English wordplay? 
Rather than generating controversy, the poor wording is generating confusion (showing how the "marketing" of science, with tricks to prove it more appealing and spread the knowledge instead can fire backwards).